# Split array of strings into more arrays of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello so what I want to do is split array of names into more arrays of names and each arrays element joined together should be smaller than specific amount of characters and none of the strings should be split in half. if it needs to be split in half then move it to the next array.
so an example would be.

```
Input: arr: ["george","ben","bob","alex","robert"] amount_of_characters: 10

Output: [["george","ben"],["bob","alex"],["robert"]]
```

Comment: Did you make an attempt at this, can you share that attempt with us? What - if anything - went wrong?

Comment: @DavidThomas I did attempt this but i couldnt manage anything i dont even know where to start

Comment: So you want to convert the flat array to nested array, but what does the `amount_of_characters` refers to?

Comment: you need to try something. otherwise it's like asking us to do an assignment for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = ["george","ben","bob","alex","robert"];
const amount_of_characters = 10;
const result = [];
let sumChars = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const word = arr[i];
  
  if (word.length + sumChars > amount_of_characters) {
    result.push([word])
    sumChars = 0;
  }
  else {
    !result.length ? result.push([word]) : result[result.length - 1].push(word);
  }
  
  sumChars += word.length;
};

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the result as:

```js
const arr = ['george', 'ben', 'bob', 'alex', 'robert'];
const amount_of_characters = 10;

let currentTotal = 0;
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const curr = arr[i];
  if (currentTotal + curr.length <= amount_of_characters) {
    currentTotal += curr.length;
    const last = result[result.length - 1];
    !last ? result.push([curr]) : result[result.length - 1].push(curr);
  } else {
    currentTotal = 0;
    result.push([]);
    i--;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function split(arr, amount_of_characters){
  let final_arr = [];
  let i = 0; // This will be used to denote which position on the original array should be filled
  let j = 0; // This will be used to denote which position on the final array should be filled
  while (i < arr.length){
    // Create a new array in the array
    final_arr[j] = [];
    let current_character_count = 0;

    // Iterate over the input array
    while (i < arr.length && arr[i].length + current_character_count < amount_of_characters){
      final_arr[j].push(arr[i]);
      current_character_count += arr[i].length;
      i++;
    }
    j++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for-of loop and access the last element of the current group using [`Array.prototype.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at):

```js
const groupByUpToNCharacters = (arr, n) => {
    const groups = [[]];
    let currGroupLength = 0;
    for (const word of arr) {
        const wordLength = word.length;
        if (currGroupLength + wordLength <= n) {
            groups.at(-1).push(word);
            currGroupLength += wordLength;
        } else {
            groups.push([word]);
            currGroupLength = wordLength;
        }
    }
    return groups;
}


const arr = ["george", "ben", "bob", "alex", "robert"];
const groupedArr = groupByUpToNCharacters(arr, 10);
console.log(groupedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what is required here is an algorithm to achieve the expected result. While multiple answers above have given elegant solutions, the below solutions use a recursive approach.

**Solution - Style-1**:

```
const joinUptoLen1 = (arr = [], mlen, i = 0) => (
  i < arr.length - 1 ?
  arr[i].length + arr[i + 1].length < mlen ?
  [
    [arr[i], arr[i + 1]]
  ].concat(joinUptoLen1(arr, mlen, i + 2)) :
  [
    [arr[i]]
  ].concat(joinUptoLen1(arr, mlen, i + 1)) :
  i === arr.length - 1 ?
  [
    [arr[i]]
  ] :
  []
);
```

The same solution written another way is shown below:

**Solution - Style-2**:

```
const joinUptoLen2 = (arr = [], mlen, i = 0) => {
  if (i < arr.length - 1) {
    if (arr[i].length + arr[i + 1].length < mlen) {
      return [
        [arr[i], arr[i + 1]]
      ].concat(joinUptoLen2(arr, mlen, i + 2));
    } else {
      return [
        [arr[i]]
      ].concat(joinUptoLen2(arr, mlen, i + 1));
    }
  } else {
    if (i === arr.length - 1) return [
      [arr[i]]
    ];
    return [];
  }
};
```

Approach is very simple. Check if sum-of-lengths of 2 consequent array-elements is lesser than the input-length. If so, make an array of the 2 elements and push this new-array into the result-array. If not, push an array with just the one element into the result-array. Recursively follow the same and handle the edge-scenario (if the last element was not included into a pair).

And here's a code snippet for quick-demo:

```js
const inpArr1 = ["george", "ben", "bob", "alex", "robert"];
const inpArr2 = ["george", "ben", "bob", "alex", "robert", "pat"];
const splitLen = 10;

const joinUptoLen1 = (arr = [], mlen, i = 0) => (
  i < arr.length - 1 ?
  arr[i].length + arr[i + 1].length < mlen ? [
    [arr[i], arr[i + 1]]
  ].concat(joinUptoLen1(arr, mlen, i + 2)) : [
    [arr[i]]
  ].concat(joinUptoLen1(arr, mlen, i + 1)) :
  i === arr.length - 1 ? [
    [arr[i]]
  ] : []
);

const joinUptoLen2 = (arr = [], mlen, i = 0) => {
  if (i < arr.length - 1) {
    if (arr[i].length + arr[i + 1].length < mlen) {
      return [
        [arr[i], arr[i + 1]]
      ].concat(joinUptoLen2(arr, mlen, i + 2));
    } else {
      return [
        [arr[i]]
      ].concat(joinUptoLen2(arr, mlen, i + 1));
    }
  } else {
    if (i === arr.length - 1) return [
      [arr[i]]
    ];
    return [];
  }
};

console.log('style-1 results: ', joinUptoLen1(inpArr1, splitLen));
console.log('style-2 results: ', joinUptoLen2(inpArr1, splitLen));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const foo = function (arr, max) { // arr - input, max - max characters in one array
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let cur = [];
    if (arr[i].length < max && i !== arr.length - 1) {
        let sum = arr[i].length;
        cur.push(arr[i]);
        while (sum <= max) {
            i++;
            if (arr[i].length + sum <= max) {
                sum += arr[i].length;
                cur.push(arr[i]);
            } else {
                sum = max + 1;
                i--;
            }
        }
    } else cur.push(arr[i]);
    result.push(cur);
}
return result;
```

};

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing it using Array.reduce():

```js
const input = ["george","ben","bob","alex","Robert"];

let idx=0;

const output = (amount_of_characters)=>{
    return input.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
        acc[idx]?null: acc.push([]);
        acc[idx].join('').length + curr.length <= amount_of_characters? 
        acc[idx].push(curr):(idx++, acc.push([]), acc[idx].push(curr)); 
        return acc;
    },[])
}

console.log(output(10));
```